# What options exist for object mapping in scala?

Tags: scala

I wish to copy (in a nested manner) values from one object tree to another. In Java I would have used something like [Orika](https://code.google.com/p/orika/).

My particular use case is building a sequence of message deltas to generate a latest state.

Answer (score 1):

Scala favours immutable values. Don't think in terms of copying - think in terms of creating a new object tree that's a transformation of the previous object tree.

You might like to use Shapeless' [generic zipper support](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes), which can apply a transformation anywhere in a nested structure of case classes or similar.

I don't understand your use case in terms of your question - perhaps you should be more specific about what you want to do. If you want to apply a message delta to a message to generate a new message, that's a case for Lenses, which are also available in Shapeless, although the implementation in Monocle is supposed to be better.

It shouldn't be necessary to use something that relies on runtime reflection - Scala is expressive enough to implement these kinds of things in a typesafe way.